# How to animate items inside Wrap widget on add and delete?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

```
 Wrap(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
          children: listItems.map((e) => CustomWidget(data: e)).toList(),
        ),
```

The children inside Wrap widget are mapped to a custom widget. These items should animate and fill existing space on adding and removing items.

How can we achieve this in Flutter?

Comment: The animation you are describing is better achieved with the `AnimatedList` widget in Flutter, rather than using a `Wrap` widget.

Comment: can you share your expected output with query.